# Is there a way to unify a json schema into a single file?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm looking for a way to unify two json schemas into one, by inserting one as a field of the other. That is to say, the schema A would have a property that is defined by the content of schema B.

To clarify,I don't want to *reference* schema A from schema B. I want to *directly insert* the content of B in a specific point of A so that I can have a single JSON document, but I figure that just "pasting" the content into the property programatically wouldn't be enough.

Comment: An example would help illustrate what it is you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

JSON Schema is designed so that you can substitute a reference with its entire contents, and the behavior will be the same, with one possible exception if you use relative URI references.

If you have a schema like "A.json":

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "b": {"$ref": "B.json"}
    }
}
```

And you have "B.json":

```
{ "type": "string" }
```

This can be collapsed into the following:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "b": { "type": "string" }
    }
}
```

There is one case in which the behavior would change, and that's if you use a relative URI reference, and the URI of the document you're substituting into causes that URI Reference to resolve to a full URI differently than it was before. Use a full (absolute) URI in the root of each schema, in these cases.

Comment: That sounds really convenient! aren't there properties that can only be present at the top though? like $schema?

Comment: Yes, that's another exception. It shouldn't be a problem in most cases, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I dint'get you question but I try to guess (it could be better if you added an example!). So i think that you have two schema like:

```
{ "schema": "A",
   ........
 }

 {"schema": "B",
   .......
  }
```

So, you have two chance to unify them:
-manually
-using a programm

Manually it is trivial because you have to do only copy and paste :

```
 { "schema": "B",
   ........

  "schema_pasted": "A",
   .......
  }
```

or you can use some library to work automatically obtaing the same result (for exaple GSON https://github.com/google/gson in Java).